# Good practice to serve static files during development in Django

Tags: django, caching

I have quite big amount of css and js files (different libraries and plugins) in my Django-1.9 project. And it takes around 3 sec to refresh a page and load all of them, which is quite long. What is the recommended way to serve those static files during development? Should I use somehow Django Cache Framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what you said, I understand that you use Django for serving static files and its performance is low and annoying.

In this case, you could apply same methods as for production use:

- use CDN (it can be faster than Django serving static files),
- set up separate web server (e.g. nginx) to serve static files,
- minimize and combine your scripts and stylesheets.